# VPN solution using Openswan

Tags: ipsec

I want to place a VPN beetween home and school because I do not trust the network down there.

If I configure the VPN server with NAT-T (nat-traversal) and configure my router to foward UDP 20 ->  UDP 500 && UDP 21 -> 4500 (I also configure the client to use UDP 20 for IKE and 21 for NAT-t) will the configuration works?

And is IKE mandatory in order to ipsec to function?

Comment: I think you're going to have a hard time convincing people here to help you subvert rules that your school has put in place. Keep in mind that many of the people here are the exact ones that are tasked with implementing and enforcing compliance with such rules.

Comment: ...additionally...not that I agree with such rules. On the contrary, I think they're ridiculous for the most part.

Comment: Um ok I see....

Comment: And I do not break any law and any contract with them. They every port else than FTP, SSH, TELNET, IMAP, SMTP. Also they block ssl other than in http.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I tried to change the port and all worked well.